# Modifying the Google Drive menu interface

Tags: google-drive-api

So I'm working on a web-app for the Google Marketplace that's going to involve integration with Google Drive. Part of what I want to be able to do with the app involves something along the lines of adding a menu option to the Drive menu interface. For instance, you could be editing a document in drive and browse to File->"My new fancy option." Does anyone know if this is possible? Or if it is not, is there another way of adding this sort of custom action functionality where you are able to perform non Drive standard actions on files from within the Drive interface?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to do so. See the documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/

Comment: Ah okay thank you, I couldn't find anything, but as long as I know it's possible that's enough for me to go forward

Comment: I couldn't find anything either by searching on the referred micro-site.